# List the hooks that can be used in .install file?

Tags: 7, hooks

I have found only few hooks that can be used in the .install file. They are:

- hook_enable
- hook_disable
- hook_install
- hook_uninstall
- hook_requirements
- hook_update_N
- hook_schema
- hook_schema_alter
- hook_update_last_removed
- hook_field_schema

Please tell me if I have left any hooks.

Comment: hook_update_dependencies - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_dependencies/7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing function

[hook_field_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7.x)

This hooks are mentioned in the "list" and "number" default module which is in "field" module.

Comment: you can give upvote as well.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no official list of the hook which can only be used in .install file. But I can give you a hint how to find some of them.

You can try to search `module_load_install` in Drupal project. Some of the hook function is called immediately after calling this function.

> This method can help to find out those hook functions which requires
>   loading of the .install file. Not only for core, but also the
>   functions provided by contrib modules .

[image]

Comment: It is a way to find other .install work only hook function provided by contrib module as well :)

Comment: For example , I  had searched in module_filter module (sites/all/modules/module_filter.install) . but I didn't get the module_load_install inside the module_filter.install. Am i doing in a right way . if I did mistake means, please help me how to find that .

Comment: @logeshvaran you should not search in .install file. `module_load_install()` is a function for Drupal to load the required .install file before implementing some of the hook functions. It is no point to find `module_load_install()` within .install file.